# Is there a global Jackson setting for @JsonIgnoreProperties(unknown=true)?

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

Is there a global Jackson setting/configuration so that I do not have to annotate every class with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(unknown=true)`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

See the APIs for [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) and [DeserializationFeature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES) for more information.

Comment: thanks. i could use some icing on the cake - how could i do this in jersey 2.0? (or even jersey 1.x)

Comment: I do not have a clue about Jersey, sorry. I did a quick search and maybe this example can help you out: http://senchado.blogspot.de/2012/10/jersey-customizing-objectmapper-to.html.

Comment: @agksmehx - you can do this in Jersey by defining a custom context resolver. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16384686/680925) for an example.

Comment: @Perception thank you. i found a different solution which i have posted as an answer alongside your answer to the other question. i would appreciate knowing if your method offers an improvement over what i used. thanks!