# 500 Internal Server Error in RESTfull

Tags: java, rest, post

When I try to access this resource this I get this error message
500 Internal Server Error

I am new to web services and I a trying to realize the issue

Rest Service

```
@Path("travelgood1")
public class TravelGood {

private LameDuck lameDuckClient;
private NiceView niceViewClient;
private SimpleDateFormat parserSDF;
private HashMap<String, List<Itinerary>> userItineraries;
private int lastItineraryId;

 public TravelGood() {
    LameDuck_Service service = new LameDuck_Service();
    lameDuckClient = service.getLameDuck();

    NiceView_Service niceViewService = new NiceView_Service();
    niceViewClient = niceViewService.getNiceView();

    parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    userItineraries = new HashMap<String, List<Itinerary>>();
}

@POST
@Path("{uid}/itineraries")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public int createItinerary(@PathParam("uid") String userId) {
    if (!userItineraries.containsKey(userId)) {
        userItineraries.put(userId, new LinkedList<Itinerary>());
    }

    Itinerary itinerary = new Itinerary(++lastItineraryId);
    userItineraries.get(userId).add(itinerary);

    return itinerary.getId();
}
}
```

Client

```
@Test
    public void TestP1() {

    WebResource clientItinerariesResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/tg/webresources/travelgood1/AnneStrandberg/itineraries");
        int itineraryId = clientItinerariesResource.post(Integer.class);
```

Comment: You should take a look on server log files. I am sure that you will find exception there. If you cannot understand the exception yourself please post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error occurs in Jersey when trying to serialize the primitive `int` to JSON. The same will happen if you use an `Integer`. Use a wrapper object/DTO for your return type (see [JAX-RS / Jersey ".get(Integer.class)" and single JSON primitive (Integer) values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408950/jax-rs-jersey-getinteger-class-and-single-json-primitive-integer-values))

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you have `NullPointerException` in this line:

```
if (!userItineraries.containsKey(userId)) {
```

It happens because `userItineraries` is not initialized. As far as I understand you try to implement some kind of cache using map. In this case initialize it:

```
private Map<String, List<Itinerary>> userItineraries = new HashMap<String, List<Itinerary>>();
```

Comment: I forgot to add the constructor
 public TravelGood() {
        LameDuck_Service service = new LameDuck_Service();
        lameDuckClient = service.getLameDuck();

        NiceView_Service niceViewService = new NiceView_Service();
        niceViewClient = niceViewService.getNiceView();

        parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        userItineraries = new HashMap<String, List<Itinerary>>();
    }

Comment: @Mitsos, in future try to avoid posting long code snippets in comment. Put such snippets into your question and if it is  needed write short comment that says that you have edited your question.